# boost.Python How to expose typedef of boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ class defined as:

```
class MyFuture {
public:
    virtual bool isDone() = 0;
    virtual const std::string& get() = 0;
    virtual void onDone(MyCallBack& callBack) = 0;
    virtual ~MyFuture() { /* empty */ } 
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyFuture> MyFuturePtr;
```

I expose the class to Python using boost.python as (this class is never created in Python but returned from an API call and thus the `noncopyable`):

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MySDK)
{
    class_<MyFuture, noncopyable>("MyFuture", no_init)
        .def("isDone", &MyFuture::isDone)
        .def("get", &MyFuture::get, return_value_policy<copy_const_reference>())
        .def("onDone", &MyFuture::onDone)
    ;
}
```

From python I use it like:

```
import MySDK

def main():
    # more code here ...
    future = session.submit()
    response = future.get
    print response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but this leads to the Python error:

```
File "main.py", line 14, in main
    future = session.submit()
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: class boost::shared_ptr<class MySDK::MyFuture>
```

How can I expose the typedef `typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyFuture> MyFuturePtr;`?

**UPDATE**

Changing the class expose using boost.Python to:

`class_<MyFuture, boost::shared_ptr<MyFuture> >("MyFuture", no_init)`

leads to the compiler error:

```
boost\python\converter\as_to_python_function.hpp(21): 
    error C2259: 'MySDK::MyFuture' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class_<MyFuture, boost::shared_ptr<MyFuture>, boost::noncopyable>("MyFuture")
```

as per the docs

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components.html#high_level_components.boost_python_class_hpp.class_template_class_t_bases_hel

Comment: @GiovanniAzua there are sections in the docs about abstract class wrappers. You're probably going to have to roll your sleeves up and have a read. My initial suspicion here is that boost::python is currently assuming that it can create a MyFuture, given the class definition you have created. Of course it can't because it's an abstract class. There must be a way to annotate it to say that there's no constructor.

Comment: @(Richard Hodges) fair enough, I have been doing that but there is no obvious documentation on this case, have been researching and thus the OP.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua found this thread. Hope it helps you: https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-cplusplus-sig/17171/

Comment: @(Richard Hodges) actually it did help! I noticed I was replacing the `noncopyable` template argument with `shared_ptr<ClusterFuture>` and they can coexist together as shows in your linked example. Please fix your answer to `class_<MyFuture, boost::shared_ptr<MyFuture>, noncopyable>("MyFuture")` and I will accept it because it solves the OP